# Derivative of unit step function?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

How would I find the derivative of a unit step function? I understand that the unit impulse function will be used but I'm not sure how to use it.

I am trying to find the derivative of this:

$v(t) = u(t+1) - 2u(t) + u(t-1)$

$u(t) = 0$  when $t < 0$

$u(t) = 1$ when $t > 0$

The relationship between unit step function and impulse function:

δ(n) = u(n) - u(n-1)

$ δ(t)=du(t)/dt $

Comment: Continuous $\displaystyle \delta(t) = \frac{d u(t)}{dt}$

Comment: Discrete $\displaystyle \delta[n] = u[n] - u[n-1] $

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to prove that the derivative of Heaviside's unit step function is the Dirac delta?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/13898/how-to-prove-that-the-derivative-of-heavisides-unit-step-function-is-the-dirac).

Comment: @arthur Thanks for the clarification. I've edited the post.

Comment: @zdub did you mean for one of the Heaviside functions to be $u(t\color{red}{+}1)$?  Otherwise the first and third terms are the same and can be simplified to $2u(t-1)$.

Comment: @Bye_World Yes, I did mean u(t+1). I've corrected it.

Answer (score 3):

The derivative of unit step $u(t)$ is Dirac delta function $\delta(t)$, since an alternative definition of the unit step is using integration of $\delta(t)$ [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heaviside_step_function).

$$u(t) = \int_{-\infty}^{t} \delta(\tau) d\tau$$

Hence,
$$\frac{dv}{dt} = \delta(t+1) - 2\delta(t) + \delta(t-1)$$

Comment: Thanks! So the graph of the derivative would just be vertical lines at t = -1, 0 and 1?

Comment: @zdub [The way that engineers draw it](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/4/48/Dirac_distribution_PDF.svg/325px-Dirac_distribution_PDF.svg.png), there should be vertical arrows at $1$ and $0$, each of which is $2$ units tall (but at $0$ it should point in the opposite direction).

Comment: @zdub You have two $u(t-1)$ in your question, or $2u(t-1)$. This means the derivative is a $2\delta(t-1)$ that is represented by an upward arrow with amplitude $2$ at $t=+1$. If your actual question is $u(t-1)+2u(t)+u(t+1)$, then there will be three upward delta functions in the derivative: two of them are at $t=\pm1$ with unit scale, and the third at origin with scale $2$.

Comment: Just to clarify: Dirac delta is NOT a function. See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/285642/is-the-dirac-delta-function-really-a-function