# Heaviside Function Derivative

Tags: distribution-theory, weak-derivatives

I came across [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/13898/how-to-prove-that-the-derivative-of-heavisides-unit-step-function-is-the-dirac) link that proves how the derivative of the heaviside function is the delta function, but I would like to ask whether -H'(-x) = $\delta$(x) in a distributional sense of course. Also, is [x$\delta$(x)]' = $\delta$(x) wrong (or right?) according to [Wolfram](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/DeltaFunction.html) on equation [17]? I am perhaps wrong as I am unfamiliar or incorrectly perceived the notations on Wolfram. Thankyou.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $H' = \delta$ we have $-H'(-x) = -\delta(-x) = -\delta(x).$
But perhaps you mean $-(H(-x))'$ (with a bit of abuse of notation)?
For that we get $-(H(-x))' = -(-\delta(-x)) = \delta(-x) = \delta(x).$

Since $x\delta = 0$ we of course have $(x\delta)' = 0.$
However, $x\delta' = (x\delta)' - (x')\delta = 0' - 1\delta = -\delta.$